# Yarn add/remove are really slow after adding a "file:" dependency?

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg

My folder structure is:

```
foo/
  bar/
    package.json
  package.json
```

`package.json` has:

```
  "workspaces": [
    "bar"
  ]
```

Eslint's `import/no-extraneous-dependencies` wants me to add `foo` to `foo/bar/package.json`. I added the dependency:

```
"foo": "file:..",
```

However, now all the Yarn commands are really slow. E.g. taking 10min to install a package that would normally take 15s. Is there something wrong with my setup?